# groupby on sparse matrix in pandas: filling them first

Tags: pandas, fill, sparse-matrix

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` with shape (1000000,3) as follows:

```
id      cat       team
1       'cat1'    A
1       'cat2'    A
2       'cat3'    B
3       'cat1'    A
4       'cat3'    B
4       'cat1'    B
```

Then I dummify with respect to the `cat` column in order to get ready for a machine learning classification.

```
df2 = pandas.get_dummies(df,columns=['cat'], sparse=True)
```

But when I try to do:

```
df2.groupby(['id','team']).sum()
```

It get stuck and the computing never ends. So instead of grouping by right away, I try:

```
df2 = df2.fillna(0)
```

But it does not work and the DataFrame is still full of `NaN` values. Why does the `fillna()` function does not fill my DataFrame as it should?
In other words, how can a pandas sparse matrix I got from get_dummies be filled with 0 instead of NaN?

I also tried:

```
df2 = pandas.get_dummies(df,columns=['cat'], sparse=True).to_sparse(fill_value=0)
```

This time, `df2` is well filled with 0, but when I try:

```
print df2.groupby(['id','sexe']).sum()
```

I get:

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.pyc in loop(labels, shape)
   3545         for i in range(1, nlev):
   3546             stride //= shape[i]
-> 3547             out += labels[i] * stride
   3548 
   3549         if xnull: # exclude nulls
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1205800,) (306994,) (1205800,)
```

My solution was to do:

```
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(np.nan_to_num(df2.as_matrix()))
df2.groupby(['id','sexe']).sum()
```

And it works, but it takes a lot of memory. Can someone help me to find a better solution or at least understand why I can't fill sparse matrix with zeros easily? And why it is impossible to use `groupby()` then `sum()` on a sparse matrix?

Comment: A general suggestion for future questions FWIW:  if possible provide a more complete example with sample data provided via numpy functions like `randn`, `tile`, and/or `repeat`.  Anytime you are getting into performance and efficiency it becomes really important to have an accurate sense of the data structure.  In your case, for example, performace of  `groupby` and `get_dummies` can tremendously vary not just with data size but with the number of distinct groups.  It's hard for folks to answer performance-related questions without knowing more about that (especially when you add in `sparse`)

Comment: Also, I don't know much about machine learning, but if you could create a reasonably short (but still complete) example going all the way from data creation to a simplified version of the machine learning code, you're likely to get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is due to mixing of dtypes.  But you could get around it like this.  First, provide only the relevant column to `get_dummies()` rather than the whole dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df['cat']).to_sparse(0)
```

After that, you can add other variables back but everything needs to be numeric.  A pandas sparse dataframe is just a wrapper on a sparse (and homogenous dtype) numpy array.

```
df2['id'] = df['id']

   'cat1'  'cat2'  'cat3'  id
0       1       0       0   1
1       0       1       0   1
2       0       0       1   2
3       1       0       0   3
4       0       0       1   4
5       1       0       0   4
```

For non-numeric types, you could do the following:

```
df2['team'] = df['team'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

This groupby seems to work OK:

```
df2.groupby('id').sum()

    'cat1'  'cat2'  'cat3'
id                        
1        1       1       0
2        0       0       1
3        1       0       0
4        1       0       1
```

An additional but possibly important point for memory management is that you can often save substantial memory with categoricals rather than string objects (perhaps you are already doing this though):

```
df['cat2'] = df['cat'].astype('category')

df[['cat','cat2']].memory_usage()

cat     48
cat2    30
```

Not much savings here for the small example dataframe but could be a substantial difference in your actual dataframe.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I did exactly what you said, but the `df2.groupby('id').sum()` is far too long, I think it is really not working. In fact the groupby operation takes no time, but it is impossible to iterate through the groupby, or use any aggregation function after it.

Comment: The problem is really the following: groupby iteration on sparse pandas DataFrame is very very very slow.

Comment: The fact is, the groupby.sum is very very fast when I don't use sparse matrix. But I need more memory.

Comment: I don't know if there is anything that could be done about that (although you could post a new question, of course).  Maybe keep the column you are grouping by in a different and non-sparse dataframe?  It might just be a case where the sparse structure saves memory but runs more slowly due to the inherent overhead of working with a sparse structure.  I am a little surprised it would make such a big difference though.

Comment: And what can I use to do the equivalent of "get_dummies"? Is there another way with Redshift or something?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  What is wrong with get_dummies?  I don't know anything about redshift.

Comment: I am looking for a general framework for classification in machine learning. My problem with get_dummies is that I can't do a groupby after it for the reason you just mentionned. That's why i am looking for another solution.

Comment: OK, sorry I can't help with that.  Sometimes there are alternatives to groupby that are faster but less convenient, but it depends on what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was tackling a similar problem before. What I did was, I applied the **groupby operation before** and **followed it up with get_dummies()**.

This worked for me as **groupby**, after formation of thousands of dummified columns (in my case), is very slow especially on sparse dataframes. It basically gave up for me. Grouping over the columns first and then dummifying made it work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['id','team'])['cat'].unique())
df.columns = ['cat']
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df[['id','team']].join(df['cat'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies().add_prefix('CAT_'))
```

Hope this helps out someone!